# How can I mention a gold tag dupe closer in the comments?

Tags: support, dupehammer, comment-replies

A question is closed by a user with a gold tag dupe hammer. I don't think the duplicate target has a valid answer to this question. But given I have less experience than the closer, I would like to ask him for some clarifications.

But `@` mention in comments doesn't give auto-complete to the user who closed the question. Is anyway I can notify/mention him?

Comment: I think that it'll notify him, it's just the auto-completion thing that doesn't work. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarounMaroun test-test not using the autocomplete.

Comment: @Roberrrt Got it :thumbs-up:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The @ mention will work, but the auto-completion feature does not. From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/295232):

> #### Why do some names not appear in the auto-complete box?
>
> ...
>
> Additionally, only users who have commented on the post are ever populated into the list. Editors and other users from the post's history will never appear there, even if they are able to be notified by typing manually.

Comment: Also, remember that spaces get removed when tagging a user.

Comment: Cool, so the only rule of the mention user name is removing space? Any escaping work required?

Comment: No escaping required. You don't even need to complete the name, just the first part will work. (Also, I have an idea now who the user is :))