# Notify dupe hammerer when OP posts a comment on the question

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, dupehammer

Ever since I received my Mjölnir I've been taking duplicate closures very seriously. When you're just one of five people casting a close vote, it's easier for other people to review the duplicate you suggested and post feedback. But when you single-handedly close a question as a duplicate, the number of people who even look at the question goes down, and the odds of someone finding fault with your duplicate are reduced. And even *if* someone finds fault with it, it's difficult for them to contact you. (I know that dupe-hammerers can be pinged if you manually type `@their_name`, but a lot of people don't.)

So whenever I close a question as duplicate, I try to re-visit the question after an hour or two to check if someone has expressed disagreement with the duplicate. This is a tedious and tiresome process, so I'd like to request a new feature that would make my life a little easier:

**If the OP posts a comment on a dupe-hammered question, send a notification to the hammerer.**

I suspect that not every hammer-wielder would be happy about such notifications, so there should probably be a switch to turn them off.

Benefits of having this feature would be:

- Faster reopening of incorrectly closed questions, reducing the asker's and potential answerers' frustration
- Less work for people like me who have to re-visit each question in search for feedback

Comment: Any poster can already do this by prepending `@` in front of the hammerer's name in comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But how many of them know that? And how many of those who know can spell my name correctly? ;(

Comment: Probably not many, but we certainly don't want to send **all** comments to the Mjölnir wielder's inbox.

Comment: In my experience it's quite rare for an OP to post a comment after their question was hammered, so I think the notifications would be manageable. If your inbox is ever flooded with notifications, there's a good chance you hammered a question incorrectly and the OP started voicing their complaints in the comments.

Comment: ..... or simply raised the ire of the poster :)

Comment: I think that your approach that you've already mentioned is best: 1) take Mjölnir use responsibility seriously, 2) review recently closed questions for comments, but more importantly, for *edits*, edits that make the original post more specific and less a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, dear, exposed my ignorance again ...

Comment: Note that I down-voted this question, not for quality reasons, but rather because I disagree with its premise. I'm "voting" on your proposal. Let's see how the others in our community feel.

Comment: Odd, having to listen to objections from the OP never made my life any easier.  All that this ever accomplishes is that even fewer users will use the hammer.  Albeit that it is the point of it.  Please do keep in mind that a significant number of users ask duplicate questions because they don't understand the existing answers, but never want to admit it.  Such users need help that is not readily available at SO.

Comment: Also there are times when I'm not sure that I *should* close the question as a dupe. In that situation I've typed out the dupe close reason "possible duplicate of...", but have not used the Mjölnir, and then leave it for others to decide. Only use the hammer when you're sure.

Comment: Would notifications of a comment *really* be *useful* though. It could be the OP replying to another comment to clarify things at which point you're still going to potentially have to come back to the question in the future to check things (unless you get notified of every comment and that'd just be noise).

Comment: The dupe closure reason does state to edit your post if it's not a duplicate and if the OP does that it kicks it into the reopen review queue where anyone can check that without burdening the dupe hammerer with notifications.

Comment: @JonClements That's a good point. I didn't realize OPs had it so easy to get their question's closure reviewed.

Comment: Along the lines of Hans' comment, notification overload is a concern with this kind of proposal. My suggestion is [leaving a comment briefly explaining why the question is a duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368032/2751851) when you use the hammer in a tricky way that feels likely to be challenged.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Unless one's in a really niche tag (in which case there's likely no gold badge holders anyway) there's going to be eyes on posts with people that can gold badge reopen it or failing that members that can vote to reopen which'll put it in the review queue as well. Stuff already happens in terms of getting stuff reopened - I don't think singling out people with notifications is necessary or would be a great experience for them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is a good suggestion for the cases in which you are genuinely unsure (as opposed to those in which you are sure, but the decision is non-trivial). I tend to write such comments as "Very closely related: [link]" rather than using the standard "Possible dupl\*cate of" phrasing, [so that the comment remains there if someone else hammers the question with a better dupe target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344519/2751851).

Comment: @Aran-Fey: understand that only the *first edit* after closure kicks the question to the reopen review queue, and so it had better be a decent non-trivial edit. What worries me more is when a concerned SO member "helps" the OP out by making a trivial edit just after question closure, messing up the OP's chance to shine.

Comment: OK, here's **my** proposal: change the site's software so that when the OP or anyone tries to comment to the dupe-hammerer using the `@` pre-pend, the site will automatically suggest the dupe-hammer user's name just as if he had written a comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels at which case you might as well extend that to editors and I have a feeling extending the (at) completion has been discussed/declined before...

Comment: @JonClements: let's avoid straw-man arguments here. I'm only suggesting one change, and each and every change should be debated in isolation and on its own merits.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sure... I'm just saying I think it's been discussed before (probably on MSE) and wasn't practical for some reason or other. Mind you with the flexibility that "Teams" offers in terms of addressing comments to people and it's all a shared code base or something - I'd imagine any previous technical objections to it would have to be re-evaluated.

Answer (score 9):

As per my comments, I disagree with your initial proposal, that all comments from the OP be directed to the Mjölnir wielder, since this risks greatly reducing the signal to noise ratio in our in-boxes, however I'd like to note that your concerns have already been touched on in this SO meta question: [How can I mention a gold tag dupe closer in the comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339827/how-can-i-mention-a-gold-tag-dupe-closer-in-the-comments)

I think that one solution would be to expand the @-notification auto-complete so that it is easier to notify the dupehammer wielder. This has already been discussed indirectly in these main site meta posts:

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)
- [Expand the username auto-completion to everyone who can be notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106534/expand-the-username-auto-completion-to-everyone-who-can-be-notified)

But I have yet to find any recent discussion on this nor any discussion that specifically mentions facilitating comments to the Mjölnir wielder. If there has been no specific discussion of this, I do agree that it should be discussed and that consideration for implementing this specific functionality be made.